# R Merging Help - cannot allocate vector of size 215.2 Mb

Tags: r, memory, merge

The message I receive is:

```
cannot allocate vector of size 215.2 Mb
```

215.2 does not seem that big to me especially when the examples I saw were in the stratosphere of 10 Gb.

The following is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
Combined<-merge(x=SubjectsYOY,y=o2017,by="subjectkey",all.x=TRUE)
```

So a pretty basic left-join.

SubjectsYOY has 28,202,411 records with 16 columns.
o2017 has 109,850 records with 94 columns.

I also need to do very similar merges three more times after I get this one done.

I tried to very much reduce the memory load by saving the objects to a .rda file on my machine, closing R, then loading the .rda in - first thing. Obviously did not work. Also, trying to avoid column removal - perhaps there is a more forgiving command instead of merge when working with this many records?

Also, would sorting the size of the two dataframes by subjectkey ahead of time help things?

I have five data frames loaded into my memory while I am trying to accomplish this. Below is some sessionInfo for what is going on with my computer:

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
Matrix products: default
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.3 plyr_1.8.4     tools_3.4.3    yaml_2.2.0     Rcpp_0.12.17
```

**Tail-end stuff follows:**

So I did some experimentation and looked at the memory.limit.

```
memory.limit()
```

It automatically is set to 32676.

Now I changed it with the following:

```
memory.limit(326760+10000)
```

And my first big merge works!

Now I have 3 more merges to go. The next one is o2018 and it again has 94 unique and new columns that need to be added to what was created before: 16 + 94 and now + 94 columns. That is a lot!

So I experimented with changing the memory limit again without understanding much about memory management:

```
memory.limit(32676000+10000)
```

Notice the two extra zeros in there now. But now I get the same original error again.

Does anyone think that combining these multiple merges into one will help? What is the code for that? Is this the best code or should I perhaps try to emulate a SQL run or something else? No matter what this will need to happen.

Thank you again!

Comment: Could you please provide some insight into your data? A minimum reproducible example is always extremely helpful.

Comment: That is a ton of columns to reproduce here. Any recommendation on how to do it for the sake of you and the rest of the community?
It is a broad combination of string fields, integers, and some floating-point numbers.
Thank you.

Comment: Try updating R to the latest version, 3.5.1? Also, have you tried the operation with a subset (say 100 rows) from each table?

Comment: If the operation succeeds with a subset, then it means it's not a syntax or type match problem, and just a memory problem. You can try a join using `data.table` which may be more memory efficient (I'm not sure though). Otherwise, you may need to spin up an AWS EC2 instance or something with more RAM. You can also run `gc()` to free up unused memory.

Comment: Also, how big are your two objects in memory? Is it possible that you're already maxing out your RAM just loading those two files?

Comment: Yes for sure it works and works well with a subset of a few thousand records. GC() happens all over the place with my code. So I am thinking that it is a memory issue.
Can anyone provide the link to upgrade to 3.5.1?
I think that I will look more closely at my merging variable - subjectkey. I think it is a big integer - maybe it will be less trying on the processor if it is character.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar situation once, and that was caused by merging texts to factors. I solved it by turning factors into characters.

Comment: So I made some progress but I am stalled again. Please see the tail-end of my posting  above to see what I did and where it sputtered out again.